# How to replace all elements of alphabetical list in google script for google doc

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to automate some doc editing. Right now, I'm trying to replace elements of a list for a quiz that are incorrect with a ~

For example, let's say that in a document I have the following, and I've already marked the correct choice using an =.

```
The capital of Norway is:
a. Haifa
=Oslo
c. Lund
d. the Hague
e. Manitoba
```

I want to create a script that will replace a., c., d., and e. each with ~

I've tried creating a function that looks like this:

```
function incorrectAnswera(){
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText("a.", "~");
}
```

But it replaces every instance of "a" and the character that follows with ~.  For example, Earth becomes E~th.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand about your goal.

Comment: Tanaike, thank you for trying!  My question was answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Text.replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for the `searchPattern`, specifically Google's [RE2 library](https://github.com/google/re2).

As a regular expression, `a.` will match the letter "a" plus *any* character following it, because `.` is a special "wildcard" character in regular expressions that matches *any* character.

As a regular expression convention, you can remove the special meaning from the `.` character with a backslash: `\.`.  However, because the Apps Script implementation takes a JavaScript string as input, you have to (annoyingly) add an **extra** backslash to get the desired effect.

`a\\.` matches the character sequence "a" followed by a period.

This will still cause havoc because if you have the sentence

> In the rain, I use an umbrella.

it will be replaced with

> In the rain, I use an umbrell~

To fix that, we need to specify that the line *starts with* our expression, and the `^` character is reserved for that.

`^a\\.` will only substitute when the line begins with "a" followed by a period.

To achieve your stated goal:

> I want to create a script that will replace a., c., d., and e. each with ~

you'll also need to use a set of characters to match which you can define with `[` and `]`.

To take your request at face value, the set would be `[acde]`, however since you are already marking the correct answer with a `=`, perhaps just using the range "a" to "e" would be better: `[a-e]` (that includes all 5 letters from a to e).

As a final detail, if you want the option of having white space in front of your `a.` sequence, you can use `\\s*` to indicate "zero or more white space characters", however the replacement may remove the white space.

```js
// mark the start of the correct answer with a "=" before running this function
function markIncorrectAnswers() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
    .replaceText("^\\s*[a-e]\\.", "~");
}
```